# How to create a claims aware custom WCF service for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, claims-based-auth, wcf, adfs, claims

I have a SharePoint 2010 instance that is Claims enabled (ADFS).

I am creating a WCF service that I need to deploy to SharePoint's _vti_bin directory.

How do I make this WCF service claims aware?

Any walkthroughs or guides would be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solutions? I am also stuck on same.